# jQuery Multiselect causes page to resize when items are selected?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the following [jquery multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic) and when checking/unchecking all or any items within the multiselect it causes the page to re-size vertically.  That is, all the controls on the page move up/down when items are selected.

The problem seems to occurs if there are other drop downs included on the page with the multi-select. By itself the multiselect works fine.  Is anybody seeing this same behavior and if so what's the workaround?

View:

```
// Multi-select
@Html.ListBox("TId", null, new { style = "width:190px;" }) 

// Dropdownlist - If this is present page re-sizes vertically. With the following line commented out multiselect doesn't move page when items are selected.
@Html.DropDownListFor(model =>
model.UserId, (SelectList)ViewBag.UserIdList, String.Empty, new { style = "width:165px;" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#TId").multiselect({
        selectedText: "Selected: #",
   minWidth: 210,
   noneSelectedText: "",
   selectedList: 2
});
</script>
```

Comment: And what's the rendered html (as seen in the 'view source,' or in the DOM with Firebug/Web Inspector/Dragonfly...)?

Answer (score 1):

A work-around might be to fix the vertical contraints of the menu via a CSS property such as margin or padding.